# Could not download image Ionic 2 File Transfer

Tags: cordova, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have been searching for days for this to work out, and trying different methods to download image with codova file transfer. But could not make it work.

Here is what i am trying

```
$scope.downloadMyFile = function(){
    var url = "http://cdn.wall-pix.net/albums/art-space/00030109.jpg";
    alert(url);
   // var targetPath = cordova.file.documentsDirectory + "testImage.png";

    var targetPath = cordova.file.dataDirectory+"testImage.png";
    var trustHosts = true;
    var options = {};

    $cordovaFileTransfer.download(url, targetPath, options, trustHosts)
      .then(function(result) {
        alert(result);
      }, function(err) {
        alert(err);
      }, function (progress) {
        // $timeout(function () {
        //   $scope.downloadProgress = (progress.loaded / progress.total) * 100;
        // });
      });
}
```

When i run it, it shows **alert(result);** Object Object

But there is no file in Directory of App

Another thing i tried is:

```
$scope.downloadMyFile = function(){
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
       var uri = encodeURI("http://s14.postimg.org/i8qvaxyup/bitcoin1.jpg");
        var fileURL =  cordova.file.dataDirectory+"testImage.jpg";;

   fileTransfer.download(
      uri, fileURL, function(entry) {
         console.log("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
      },

      function(error) {
         console.log("download error source " + error.source);
         console.log("download error target " + error.target);
         console.log("download error code" + error.code);
      },

      false, {
         headers: {
            "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
         }
      }
   );
}
```

It also says download complete, but there is no file.

What i am doing wrong?